# Countdown timer is not working

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I want a 30 minute countdown timer. I had insert this timer in 2 places(top & bottom of my website). Both timers have the same code. But only 1 timer works and the other doesn't shows. Why is it so? Is there something wrong with the code?

Can you show a different code that achieves the same results, without any errors.

```js
function countdown() {
    time = parseInt(localStorage.time);

    if (isNaN(time) || time > (30*60)) {
        //alert("An error occured: time left variable is corrupted, resetting timer");
        localStorage.time = 30 * 60;
        countdown();
        return null;
    }

    if (time <= 0) {
        //alert("Your Timer Has Run Out! We Still Got 2 Copies Left, You Could Still Try!");
        return null;
    }
  
    document.getElementById('timeleft').innerText = formatTime(time);
    time--;
    localStorage.time = time;
    setTimeout('countdown()', 1000);
}

function formatTime(time) {
    minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
    seconds = time - minutes * 60;
  
    if (String(seconds).length == 1) {
        return String(minutes) + ":0" + String(seconds);
    }
  
    return String(minutes) + ":" + String(seconds);
}

countdown();
```

```html
<font size="+26"><div id="timeleft"></div></font>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its probably because you are using ID to reference the timer containers. When you use `getElementById`, you will always get the first element having the respective ID.

Using raw javascript (without any framework like jQuery), you may use something like [getElementsByClassName()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp), that will return you all incidences of the specific class.

**Example:**

**1) Using `class` attribute instead `id`:**

```
<div class="timeleft"></div>
```

**Your implementation can be like this:**

```
var timers = document.getElementsByClassName('timeleft');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(timers, function(timer) {
    timer.innerText = formatTime(time);
})
```

**EDIT: Here is the solution applied to your code:**

```
function countdown() {
  time = parseInt(localStorage.time);

  if(isNaN(time) || time > (30 * 60)) {
    //alert("An error occured: time left variable is corrupted, resetting timer");
    localStorage.time = 30 * 60;
    countdown();
    return null;
  }

  if(time <= 0) {
    //alert("Your Timer Has Run Out! We Still Got 2 Copies Left, You Could Still Try!");
    return null;
  }

  var timers = document.getElementsByClassName('timeleft');

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(timers, function(timer) {
    timer.innerText = formatTime(time);
  })

  time--;
  localStorage.time = time;
  setTimeout('countdown()', 1000);
}

function formatTime(time) {
  minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
  seconds = time - minutes * 60;

  if(String(seconds).length == 1) {
    return String(minutes) + ":0" + String(seconds);
  }

  return String(minutes) + ":" + String(seconds);
}

window.onload = function() {
  countdown();
}
```

You can test the solution with this 2 (or more) tags spread in your code:

```
<div class="timeleft"></div>
<div class="timeleft"></div>
```

**Preview of my test:**

[image: Preview of my test]

Following this approach, you can add how many timers you want in your page, without the necessity to make javascript changes :)

PS: You should look at [jQuery](https://jquery.com/). It can let your life much more easier, having such more clean implementations.

Comment: @thanks, the code section of website only accepts only javascript & html.

Comment: No problem @Doing97. Considering your context, i strongly recommend you to use `getElementsByClassName()` instead of `getElementById`. The second one its not scalable. You will need to add more functions calls ever time you need to add a new timer.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but after i tried implementing it, both the timers freeze(pause/ don't work). Can you show your complete code?

Comment: @Doing97 hey my friend. I made an update to the answer putting the full solution. if you get any problems with it, let me know :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, words can't describe my happiness.

Answer (score 0):

Your function will write to an element with id `"timeleft"`.  The call below will only choose one instance of an element with that id.

```
document.getElementById('timeleft').innerText = formatTime(time);
```

For the second timer you would have to use a different element, or class, or another approach.

```
    function countdown(domId) {
    time = parseInt(localStorage['time' + domId]);

    if (isNaN(time) || time > (30*60)) {
        //alert("An error occured: time left variable is corrupted, resetting timer");
        localStorage.time = 30 * 60;
        countdown(domId);
        return null;
    }

    if (time <= 0) {
        //alert("Your Timer Has Run Out! We Still Got 2 Copies Left, You Could Still Try!");
        return null;
    }

    document.getElementById(domId).innerText = formatTime(time);
    time--;
    localStorage['time' + domId] = time;
    setTimeout('countdown("' + domId + '")', 1000);
}

function formatTime(time) {
    minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
    seconds = time - minutes * 60;

    if (String(seconds).length == 1) {
        return String(minutes) + ":0" + String(seconds);
    }

    return String(minutes) + ":" + String(seconds);
}

countdown('timeleft');
countdown('secondTimer');
```

and you would have to define another DOM element with id `"secondTimer"`, basically copy of what you have, i.e.

```
<font size="+26"><div id="secondTimer"></div></font>
```

Comment: @Jerek both the timers pause/don't work with this code. Anyways, thanks for your help.

Comment: ah yes, I see, hang in

Comment: @Doing97 try now

Comment: @Jerek the both timers are counting 2 seconds for 1 second of time.

Comment: see it for yourself. I applied your code to my website.

Comment: @jerek did you see the issue?

Comment: @Doing97  yes, it changes value by 2,  you are using local storage, so each time one of the calls is made it affects the other

Comment: @Doing97 I've made a quick fix, but I have't tested it.  Fixed, try now it might work.

Comment: 2 seconds counting.

Answer (score 0):

update: using `class`

```js
function countdown() {
  time = parseInt(localStorage.time);

  if(isNaN(time) || time > (30 * 60)) {
    //alert("An error occured: time left variable is corrupted, resetting timer");
    localStorage.time = 30 * 60;
    countdown();
    return null;
  }

  if(time <= 0) {
    //alert("Your Timer Has Run Out! We Still Got 2 Copies Left, You Could Still Try!");
    return null;
  }

  document.getElementsByClassName('timeleft')[0].innerText = formatTime(time);
  document.getElementsByClassName('timeleft')[1].innerText = formatTime(time);
  time--;
  localStorage.time = time;
  setTimeout('countdown()', 1000);
}

function formatTime(time) {
  minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
  seconds = time - minutes * 60;

  if(String(seconds).length == 1) {
    return String(minutes) + ":0" + String(seconds);
  }

  return String(minutes) + ":" + String(seconds);
}

countdown();
```

```html
<font size="+26"><div class="timeleft"></div></font>
<font size="+26"><div class="timeleft"></div></font>
```

Comment: thanks for the code, but after implementing your changes, both the timers freeze(pause). Can you show the complete code?

Comment: try delete  `function countdown(domId){...}`